# Casting an [Float] to [simd_float4] in Swift

Tags: c, swift, simd

I have this c function that I call from Swift but I think it should be possible to implement in Swift, the trick is to be able to cast the memory for the array of floats to an array of simd_float4. Below is my c function and how I call it in Swift

swift

```
sumFloats(&y, y1, n, anAmplitudes[z]);
```

C

```
void sumFloats(float * y, const float * x, const int yc, const float a) {
    simd_float4 theA = simd_make_float4(a,a,a,a);
    simd_float4 * theY = (simd_float4*)y;
    simd_float4 * theX = (simd_float4*)x;
    assert( (yc&0x3) == 0 );
    for( int t = 0, theYC = yc >> 2; t < theYC; t ++ ) {
        theY[t] += theA * theX[t];
    }
}
```

also my understanding is an Array doesn't guarantee a continuous block of memory so there must some conversion going on when calling the C code, I can probable fix that by using a ContiguousArray, but I can't use a ContiguousArray to call C.

Comment: Sounds like a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: If `simd_float4` is anything like Intel's intrinsic types in C/C++, then it's fine: the aliasing rules for `__m128*` are like `char*`: it can alias anything.

Comment: Wouldn't `t+=4` step by 4 vectors, not 4 floats?  Only if you were casting to a SIMD type from `float` inside the loop would you want `+=4`.  Unless pointer math on `simd_float4` is very weird and +1 steps by only 1/4 of its width.

Comment: I just wonder why the function is called “sumFloats” – it multiplies all elements of a vector by a common scalar.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That looks indeed wrong, `t` should be incremented by one. – It *could* be a typo, since the upper bound (`yc/4`)  looks good.

Comment: Yes, it should be += 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withUnsafe(Mutable)BufferPointer()` can be used to get a pointer to the array's (mutable) storage, and `withMemoryRebound()`  to access the array of `Float` as an array of `float4`:

```
func sumFloats(y: inout [Float], x: [Float], yc: Int, a: Float) {
    let theA = simd_float4(a, a, a, a)
    x.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: simd_float4.self, capacity: yc / 4) { theX in
            y.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
                $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: simd_float4.self, capacity: yc / 4) { theY in
                    for t in 0..<yc/4 {
                        theY[t] = theA * theX[t]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let x: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
var y: [Float] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

sumFloats(y: &y, x: x, yc: 8, a: 2.0)
print(y) // [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how Apple define the vForce functions Martin R's answer can be simplified as;

```
func sumFloats(y: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, x: UnsafePointer<Float>, yc: Int, a: Float) {
    let theA = simd_float4(a, a, a, a)
    x.withMemoryRebound(to: simd_float4.self, capacity: yc / 4) { theX in
        y.withMemoryRebound(to: simd_float4.self, capacity: yc / 4) { theY in
            for t in 0..<yc/4 {
                theY[t] += theA * theX[t]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it can still be called the same way with [Float] arguments.